# my website's live version & hpanel appearing differently

Tags: wordpress, blogs

when someone visits amitindoria.com (that's my website) the blog posts are not visible to the visitor and it shows a blank space there but when you move your mouse over that blank section it showed the hand symbol (which means something clickable is there) and when you click on it. it shows you the blog post.
I have contacted with hosting provider and do all that he said to me like restorations, re-installing the theme again. but the issues remain the same.
please help me to fix this.
attaching the images please have a look [image when a visitor visit the website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NGyQ.png)

[when I logged in to the website's admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n2CJ.png)

Comment: It seems to work just fine for me

Comment: because I resorted the files from the last month and worked fine for some days and from yesterday it again behaving like mentioned in the above question.

Comment: Looks like a issue with page cache, are you using any caching plugin ? and when it breaks are there errors in the developer console ?